# Create multiple rows based off a date range

Tags: oracle11g, date-range, connect-by

I have a calendar query and a table below. I have a StartDate and end date for a member. Also on my calendar table I have captured a "Weekof"  based on the startDate. I would like to capture if a member is active anytime during that weekof. See expected results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  --CA.CALENDAR_DATE,
      TO_CHAR(CALENDAR_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CALENDAR_DATE                                
           TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(CALENDAR_DATE, 'Monday') - 7, 'MM/DD/YY-') || 
      TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(CALENDAR_DATE, 'Monday') - 1, 'MM/DD/YY') AS WEEK_OF_YEAR,

      ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY CALENDAR_DATE) AS MasterCalendar_RNK

     FROM CALENDAR CA
     WHERE 1=1  
       --AND CA.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -12) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       --AND CA.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) -5 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       ORDER BY TO_DATE(CALENDAR_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC
```

Table

```
Member    StartDate    EndDate    
  A          1/31/17      
  B          2/1/17      2/15/17
```

Expected output:

```
Member    StartDate    EndDate    Week_Of_Year        Active
  A         1/31/17                  1/30/17-2/5/17      1
  A         1/31/17                  2/6/17-2/12/17      1
  A         1/31/17                  2/13/17-2/19/17     1
  B         2/1/17      2/15/17      1/30/17/2/5/17      1
  B         2/1/17      2/15/17      2/6/17-2/12/17      1
  B         2/1/17      2/15/17      2/13/17-2/19/17     1
```

Current Query:

```
WITH MASTER_CALENDAR AS (
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 - LEVEL , A.CALENDAR_DATE
FROM (SELECT C.CALENDAR_DATE FROM MST.CALENDAR C WHERE 1=1 AND C.CALENDAR_DATE > SYSDATE-30 AND C.CALENDAR_DATE < SYSDATE) A

WHERE 1=1

CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 --NEED TO UPDATE?

ORDER BY A.CALENDAR_DATE  DESC       
                         ),

ActiveMembers AS (
SELECT H.CLT_CLT_PGMID, H.START_DT

  ,CASE WHEN TRUNC(H.END_DT) = '1-JAN-3000' 
  THEN SYSDATE 
  ELSE TO_DATE(H.END_DT) 
  END AS END_DT

 FROM H
 WHERE 1=1 
  AND H.CLT_CLT_PGMID IN ('1','2','3')
                        )

SELECT CLT_CLT_PGMID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, WEEK_OF_YEAR, ACTIVE -- but not week_start
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT A.CLT_CLT_PGMID,
  TO_CHAR(A.START_DT, 'MM/DD/YY') AS STARTDATE,
  TO_CHAR(A.END_DT, 'MM/DD/YY') AS ENDDATE,
  NEXT_DAY(CAL.CALENDAR_DATE, 'Monday') - 7 AS WEEK_START, -- for ordering later
  TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(CAL.CALENDAR_DATE, 'Monday') - 7, 'MM/DD/YY-') || 
    TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(CAL.CALENDAR_DATE, 'Monday') - 1, 'MM/DD/YY') AS WEEK_OF_YEAR,
  1 AS ACTIVE

FROM ActiveMembers A
  INNER JOIN MASTER_CALENDAR CAL ON CAL.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN A.START_DT AND A.END_DT
                                                                     --BETWEEN TO_CHAR(A.START_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND COALESCE(A.END_DT,(SYSDATE))                                                                  
                                      ) 
WHERE 1=1

ORDER BY 
CLT_CLT_PGMID , STARTDATE, ENDDATE, WEEK_START
                    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the calendar query currently generates strings, it would be simpler to go back to the calendar table, join that to your member/date table, and regenerate the week range string:

With CTEs to represent your calendar table (just with dates for the last few weeks for now) and member data:

```
with calendar(calendar_date) as (
  select trunc(sysdate) + 1 - level from dual connect by level <= 42
),
mytable (member, startdate, enddate) as (
  select cast('A' as varchar2(6)), date '2017-01-31', cast (null as date) from dual
  union all select cast('B' as varchar2(6)), date '2017-02-01', date '2017-02-15' from dual
)
select member, startdate, enddate, week_of_year, active -- but not week_start
from (
    select distinct m.member,
      to_char(m.startdate, 'MM/DD/YY') as startdate,
      to_char(m.enddate, 'MM/DD/YY') as enddate,
      next_day(c.calendar_date, 'Monday') - 7 as week_start, -- for ordering later
      to_char(next_day(c.calendar_date, 'Monday') - 7, 'MM/DD/YY-') || 
        to_char(next_day(c.calendar_date, 'Monday') - 1, 'MM/DD/YY') as week_of_year,
      1 as active
    from mytable m
    join calendar c
    on c.calendar_date between m.startdate and coalesce(m.enddate, trunc(sysdate))
)
order by member, startdate, enddate, week_start;
```

gets

```
MEMBER STARTDAT ENDDATE  WEEK_OF_YEAR          ACTIVE
------ -------- -------- ----------------- ----------
A      01/31/17          01/30/17-02/05/17          1
A      01/31/17          02/06/17-02/12/17          1
A      01/31/17          02/13/17-02/19/17          1
A      01/31/17          02/20/17-02/26/17          1
B      02/01/17 02/15/17 01/30/17-02/05/17          1
B      02/01/17 02/15/17 02/06/17-02/12/17          1
B      02/01/17 02/15/17 02/13/17-02/19/17          1
```

You haven't specified an upper limit for members with no end-date, so I've used today, via `coalesce()`.

The inner query is only needed for ordering, as the week range string can't be used, and you don't want to see the week start on its own; and you can't use distinct and order by a field you aren't selecting.

Comment: I only need the last 30 days of the calendar, so i added a subquery for the results. I'm not familar with connect by but I changed the connect by level from <= 42 to <= 1  I'm not sure what this does. Could you explain and the query works for my examples but don't understand the how.

Comment: My current query is displayed under my question based upon your answer.

Comment: @John - the 42 limits how many rows the connect-subquery returns. There's no particular relevance to that number, I just picked one that would generate at least enough dates for your example data. If you run that subquery on its own you'll see it generates a range of individual dates. If you change the 42 to 30 it will generate the last 30 days instead of the last 42. (Changing it to 1 will only show 1 date). But if you're getting the dates from your calendar table, you don't need the connect-by at all. (I said the CTEs were to represent your real data.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in a similar way to Alex, but slightly different. Seeing as your weeks start with a Monday, I'd use `TRUNC(dt, 'iw')` to get the ISO start of the week (which happens to be defined as a Monday) for the specified date. Then I'd get the distinct values of those before joining to your table, like so:

```
with calendar as (select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 calendar_date
                  from   dual
                  connect by level <= 50),
   your_table as (select 'A' member, date '2017-01-31' startdate, NULL enddate from dual union all
                  select 'B' member, date '2017-02-01' startdate, date '2017-02-15' enddate from dual)
select yt.member,
       yt.startdate,
       yt.enddate,
       to_char(c.week_start, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
         || ' - ' || to_char(c.week_start + 6, 'mm/dd/yyyy') week_of_year,
       1 as active
from   your_table yt
       inner join (select distinct trunc(cl.calendar_date, 'iw') week_start
                   from   calendar cl) c on c.week_start <= nvl(yt.enddate, SYSDATE) AND c.week_start + 6 >= yt.startdate
order by yt.member,
         c.week_start;
MEMBER STARTDATE  ENDDATE    WEEK_OF_YEAR                ACTIVE
------ ---------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------
A      01/31/2017            01/30/2017 - 02/05/2017          1
A      01/31/2017            02/06/2017 - 02/12/2017          1
A      01/31/2017            02/13/2017 - 02/19/2017          1
A      01/31/2017            02/20/2017 - 02/26/2017          1
B      02/01/2017 02/15/2017 01/30/2017 - 02/05/2017          1
B      02/01/2017 02/15/2017 02/06/2017 - 02/12/2017          1
B      02/01/2017 02/15/2017 02/13/2017 - 02/19/2017          1
```

Like Alex, I've assumed your null enddate runs up until today (sysdate). However, looking at your results for member B, it looks like you're looking for an overlapping range (since 30th Jan is not between 1st and 15th Feb), so I've amended my join clause accordingly. This results in an extra row for member A, so maybe you're wanting to run null enddates up until the previous Sunday of sysdate? Not sure. I'm sure you'll be able to amend that yourself, if you need to.